# Fastboot poweroff command

Tags: fastboot, command-line

Is there a way to shutdown my Mate7 from fastboot? Long pressing the power button makes the phone restart again. I need to shut it down so I can recharge it then restore to stock.

Answer (score 9):

There is no Fastboot Command that does this.

However you could try holding the power button down until the screen goes blank and then letting go off the power button before the device starts to boot (before the vibrate). This is the only viable way... The list of available Fastboot commands are:

```
usage: fastboot [ <option> ] <command>

 

commands:

  update <filename>                        reflash device from update.zip

  flashall                                 flash boot + recovery + system

  flash <partition> [ <filename> ]         write a file to a flash partition

  erase <partition>                        erase a flash partition

  format <partition>                       format a flash partition

  getvar <variable>                        display a bootloader variable

  boot <kernel> [ <ramdisk> ]              download and boot kernel

  flash:raw boot <kernel> [ <ramdisk> ]    create bootimage and flash it

  devices                                  list all connected devices

  continue                                 continue with autoboot

  reboot                                   reboot device normally

  reboot-bootloader                        reboot device into bootloader

  help                                     show this help message

 

options:

  -w                                       erase userdata and cache (and format

                                           if supported by partition type)

  -u                                       do not first erase partition before

                                           formatting

  -s <specific device>                     specify device serial number

                                           or path to device port

  -l                                       with "devices", lists device paths

  -p <product>                             specify product name

  -c <cmdline>                             override kernel commandline

  -i <vendor id>                           specify a custom USB vendor id

  -b <base_addr>                           specify a custom kernel base address

  -n <page size>                           specify the nand page size. default:

2048

  -S <size>[K|M|G]                         automatically sparse files greater th

an
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to charge your phone enough so that you can flash again, try this

```
@echo off
:start
fastboot getvar battery-voltage

fastboot reboot-bootloader

ping /n 6 localhost >nul

goto start
```

save it as a batch file and place it in adb and run it.

This will basically make your phone to reboot the bootloader continuously until you reach a safe battery level for flashing.

Comment: The `ping` command after you tell it to `reboot` is pointless, because the device will have rebooted. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

ok i got it .. also problem fixed and phone working now .. all i had to do is to put phone in SD Update Mode where it says "Battery Level is Low" then i connected charger and left it for 2 hours then Update process started.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
fastboot oem poweroff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

*fastboot reboot-bootloader*

At which point you can use the bootloader menu to shut it down. I believe in pretty much all, if not all, Android bootloaders you can select to power down by either pressing volume down 3 times or volume up 1 time. Pressing the power button should then select to power down. I'm not sure this will work for Mohamed Shibo's original scenario, but it's what I had to do recently to shut down a Droid Turbo that was stuck in continual boot with a broken screen.

Comment: This varies between devices. There is no standard here. For example, for my Motorola Nexus 6, your answer applies ( and there is no need, at least in my device, to reboot into bootloader again). For OnePlus One, it doesn't work. I don't particularly remember the device name but it doesn't work for a particularly high end Moto device either.

Answer (score 0):

Had an issue with Motorola X4 where power button was not working.
Have started phone into recovery mode by pressing volume down button and plugging in the USB cable.
After entering `fastboot devices` my device was listed.
Using commands `fastboot reboot` or `fastboot continue` I've got next error:

```
ERROR: could not clear output pipe; result e00002ed, ignoring....
Resuming boot
```

To accept `fastboot continue` command I've needed to disconnect USB cable, enter command, confirm it, and plug in USB cable back into the phone, and it booted.

Steps:

1. Boot phone into recovery mode (Press volume down button and plug in USB cable connected to charger or PC)
2. Disconnect phone from PC
3. Enter `fastboot continue` press enter
4. Connect phone to PC

Answer (score 0):

Not all recovery have a poweroff.

Good time to install TWRP.

Some phones will overwrite once started, but should give you a chance to install it.

You don't need to write anything else but that new recovery (different partition than System) to phone and TWRP alone will not root your phone or remove your data (but be sure to write to recovery part of phone and use correct version, consult forums esp. on xda-developer and twrp.me).
It have a nice interface and should allow you to turn phone off among other stuff.

( --

My Xiaomi started asking to activate and then failing doing it, so close to bricked.

Planning to go away from stock ROM and root the phone, but missing paperclip and phone have decided to encrypt the SD-card, so looking for a shutdown too which broght me here :P.

Until I can go to a local store to exchange the card with a card I just written various stuff to.

**** Xiaomi :P .. It overwrites TWRP, encrypt, require verification and generally takes a long step towards bugging me.

Screen also got a crack from very little (was protected with a overlay and casing.

--)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).